# Visual Studio designer how to automatically create associations

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

Based on a project is it possible to automatically generate a class diagram with all associations? I'm trying to generate a class diagram from my NHibernate POCOs that will display what the associations are between each model. So if I had a one to many relationship (`IList<>`) between class `Foo` and `Bar` then I'd expect to see `Foo -->> Bar` and so on.

The only thing I can see is dragging my classes onto the diagram canvas and manually creating the associations. Problem with that is Visual Studio will start creating additional properties in my classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 Profesional will not draw the associations for you. You must manually right-click the `IList<T>` element (or whatever list you have) and select "Draw Associations".